# Spring Boot: database initialization fails with "Referential integrity constraint violation" on init SQL scripts

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to refine the "TacoOrder" application from "Spring in Action" a bit and am setting up database initialization for a H2 database from my Spring Boot application.

This is done by adding two data initialization scripts as described in [Initialize a Database Using Basic SQL Scripts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts)

The DDL script `schema-h2.sql`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ingredient;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ingredient_type;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ingredient_type (
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    index INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    exclusive BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    mandatory BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ingredient (
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- "enum-like" name, lower-cased
    description CHAR(100) NOT NULL,      -- a cleartext description
    type VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(type) REFERENCES ingredient_type(name)
);
```

The DML script `data-h2.sql`

```
INSERT INTO ingredient_type (name, index, exclusive, mandatory)
VALUES ('wrap', 1, true, true),
       ('protein', 2, false, false),
       ('veggies', 3, false, false),
       ('cheese', 4, false, false),
       ('sauce', 5, false, true);

INSERT INTO ingredient (name, description, type)
VALUES ('flto', 'Flour Tortilla', 'wrap'),
       ('coto', 'Corn Tortilla', 'wrap'),
       ('grbf', 'Ground Beef', 'protein'),
       ('carn', 'Carnitas', 'protein'),
       ('tmto', 'Diced Tomatoes', 'veggies'),
       ('letc', 'Lettuce', 'veggies'),
       ('ched', 'Cheddar', 'cheese'),
       ('jack', 'Monterrey Jack', 'cheese'),
       ('slsa', 'Salsa', 'sauce'),
       ('srcr', 'Sour Cream', 'sauce');
```

The above being introduced by the appropriate entry in `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always # also initialize for non-in-memory databases
      platform: h2 # use the script that have "h2" in their name
```

This is all very common.

Graphically, the database schema is:

[image: database schema]

If I run the above scripts manually (in order "schema" then "data", naturally), everything works fine and the desired pre-filled tables appear in the H2 database.

If I start the Spring Boot application, the tables appear in the H2 database but the data prefill fails with a constraint violation:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential
   integrity constraint violation: "CONSTRAINT_10: PUBLIC.INGREDIENT
   FOREIGN KEY(TYPE) REFERENCES PUBLIC.INGREDIENT_TYPE(NAME) ('wrap')";
SQL statement:
   INSERT INTO ingredient (name, description, type) VALUES
   ('flto', 'Flour Tortilla', 'wrap'),
   ('coto', 'Corn Tortilla', 'wrap'),
   ('grbf', 'Ground Beef', 'protein'), ... [23506-220]
```

In the application log, we see:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt ...
Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of file [.../data-h2.sql]
```

I surmise that for some reason the filling of table `ingredient_type` is not done, or skipped. But why?

In fact, if I remove the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, I end up with a filled `ìngredient` table and an empty `ingredient_type` table. Then the application still doesn't run because there is no data of course.

**Experiment #1**

Another trial whereby I add the definition and data for a third table, while leaving out the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS taco (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    when_created DATETIME,
    when_updated DATETIME
)
```

```
INSERT INTO taco (id, when_created, when_updated)
VALUES (1, '2023-01-01 12:00:00', '2023-01-01 13:00:00');
```

...results in tables `ingredient` and `taco` filled, and `ingredient_type` not filled. Looks like there is something peculiar about that table? But again, running the DDL DML scripts manually works fine.

**Experiment #2**

Aha, it seems just that the first `INSERT` in the DML file is being ignored by Spring Boot. If one moves the statement to fill table `ingredient` to the top of the DML file, it is table `ingredient` that remains empty. Similarly moving the statement to fill table `taco` to the top means that `taco` gets the silent treatment. But why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a C++-style comment at the top of the DML file:

```
// convention: "string-based" keys are always fully lowercase!
```

If one removes this comment, the first `INSERT` is picked by the Spring Boot application initialization, otheriwse it is dropped.

One may note that `//` comments are sort-of allowed in H2:

[H2 comments in SQL](https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#comment)

[image: Comments in H2]

> Compatibility-only non-standard syntax is marked in red, don't use it unless you need it for compatibility with other databases or old versions of H2.

In fact, replacing the `//` by `/* ... */` ("bracketed comment") fixes the problem.

It is possible that running the DML script from the IDE strips the comment before passing it the H2 driver, which would explain why it works in that case.

Feels vaguely buggy. But where do I complain? Spring? H2?

This is *h2-2.2.220* btw.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the following property to your configuration:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

The default value for this property is create-drop.  If not explicitly set to another value this can result in data being deleted that has been inserted during DB initialization via SQL scripts.

Comment: Thank you. No, that didn't change anything, sadly.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is change the format of your sql scripts so that you are not using a single insert with multi value.  Have each line have insert statement.  INSERT INTO ingredient_type (name, index, exclusive, mandatory)
VALUES ('wrap', 1, true, true);
INSERT INTO ingredient_type (name, index, exclusive, mandatory) VALUES ('protein', 2, false, false);  etc...

Comment: That didn't work either ... but it turns out that the first INSERT in the DML file is summarily ignored by Spring Boot. Why?

Comment: Found it ... it's a comment line that does it (really!)

Comment: Excellent.  Congrats.  I would post something to H2 to see if they are stripping, escaping to allow work from IDE.